# Push lambda to C++ STL queue cause Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, android-ndk

I want to push lambda in a queue. This lambda will be poped and executed into another thread. And current thread will wait until lambda is executed and return some result:

```
void * EglThread::execute(const std::function<void * ()> f) {
    std::condition_variable lambdaExecutedCond;
    void * out;
    bool exceptionFlag = false;
    std::exception exception;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(this->mutex);
    this->queue.push([&]() -> void {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> __unused lock(this->mutex);
        lambdaExecutedCond.notify_one();

        try {
            out = f();
        } catch (const std::exception & e) {
            exceptionFlag = true;
            exception = e;
        }
    });
    this->cond.notify_all();
    lambdaExecutedCond.wait(lk);

    if (exceptionFlag) {
        throw exception;
    } else {
        return out;
    }
}

void EglThread::run() {
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(this->mutex);
        if (this->queue.empty()) {
            if (this->flagShutdown) {
                break;
            } else {
                this->cond.wait(lk);
            }
        } else {
            this->queue.front()();
            this->queue.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

But I have Segmentation fault error during `push` operation. The log looks like:

```
EglThread::execute().

Queue pushing...

Segmentation fault
```

And I can't figure out what could be wrong.
`queue` object declared as class member, without excplicit call for its constructor. Just like this:

```
std::queue<std::function<void ()>> queue;
```

Comment: I have no idea why it fails where it fails, but you should be happy that it fails so early: there is no way the lambda would actually work when you run it, because it captures `mutex` by reference. When you run lambda from the queue, the mutex would be long gone out of scope.

Comment: framing your question in terms of an MCVE will certainly get you an answer. We can't compile incomplete code snippets.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @dasblinkenlight why the `mutex` will be out of scope? The method which creates lambda will not be finished, until lambda is executed. So all local variables will be "alive"

Comment: You don't actually execute the lambda inside `EglThread::execute`, you only push it into the queue. And the mutex is not the only variable you capture by reference *and use* in the lambda. You also return the uninitialized variable `out` from `EglThread::execute`.

Comment: @MaximMetelskiy I do not see code that takes lambda off the queue to run it. Is there another thread running concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example(simplified):

```cpp
Log<ANDROID_LOG_INFO>("Queue pushing...\n");
this->queue.push([&]() -> void { /*...*/ } );
Log<ANDROID_LOG_INFO>("Queue pushed\n");
```

we can see that the issue is on the `queue.push` part.
Which is what You should focus on.

So possible causes are:

1. the `queue` is incorrrectly initialized,
2. during the creation of the lambda "object", some data may be copied which is causing this segmentation fault.

For the first cause I made a minimal example repeating your code:
The diffrence is I put the queue into the function.

```cpp
void execute( const std::function<void* ()> f )
{
    std::queue<std::function<void* ()>> queue;

    queue.push( [ & ]() -> void*
    {
        return f();
    } );
}

int main()
{
    execute( []() -> void*
    {
        return nullptr;
    } );
}
```

This works no problem. But this is single threaded! Need more info from You to explain how/when theses functions are executing. Especially the race conditions.

Just because you use mutexes, doesn't mean you are that safe.

The second cause is more difficult to trace.

For debugging, inside the lambda, I would comment out each line one at a time and see if this helps to overcome the segmentation fault.
Then we can find the cause more easily.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've found, that the problem caused is by `queue` object. If I create a local `queue` variable, like in your example, `queue.push()` works ok. But if I try to use a queue, which is a member of class, I got a segment fault. So, I don't initialize it in any special way. It's just declared as a private field (as I described in quastion). What could be the error?

Comment: I found the problem. It caused by the order of creating fields in constructor in outter classes